# How do i put an image from google docs into swift app?

Tags: swift, image, google-drive-api

I'm finding it difficult finding resources online about how I can put a google docs image into my swift app programatically. The user will upload an image publicly to the google drive, then within my app I should be able to view the image. I'm essentially using google drive as a form of data base storage. 
Any help on how this can be possible is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `The user will upload an image publicly to the google drive` please explain this portion elaborately.

Comment: Basically, I'm using a google form, the user will fill in a questionare and then will upload an image as one of the questions through the File Upload option on google forms. For example the user will take a picture of a resume and submit it as an answer on the form. Once it is uploaded it goes to a public folder which can be accessed with the link to any specific image.

Comment: Since you know the folder where the images are uploaded, try setting it as a parameter `parentID` when using [`Files: get`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) from there can list images, get thumbnails. Try using Drive API Rest sample for [iOS](https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client-for-rest/tree/master/Examples/DriveSample) as a guide. Also, you can [search for files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-parameters#examples_for_fileslist) in a specific folder the display it to your app.